# How to show only one trace when plotly updatemenus load on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have two graphs that I want to show using `plotly`'s `updatemenus` feature. I am able to populate and display the data using the `updatemenus` feature. However, when the plot loads, both the graphs are displayed initially. Is there a way to show only one graph when the plot loads initially?

I went through the documentation for `updatemenus` on `plotly` but could not find any attribute that will help me in achieving this.

```
trace28 = go.Bar(x=for1.head()['Name'],
                 y=for1.head()['G'],
                 name='Goals',
                 opacity=0.8
                )

trace29 = go.Bar(x=for1.head()['Name'],
                 y=for1.head()['A'],
                 name='Assists',
                 opacity=0.8
                )

trace30 = go.Bar(x=for2.head()['Name'],
                 y=for2.head()['G'],
                 name='Goals',
                 opacity=0.8
                )

trace31 = go.Bar(x=for2.head()['Name'],
                 y=for2.head()['A'],
                 name='Assists',
                 opacity=0.8
                )


updatemenus = list([dict(active=-1,
                         type='buttons',
                         buttons=list([dict(label='2011/12',
                                           method='update',
                                           args=[dict(visible=[True, True, False, False]),
                                                 dict(title='<b>Forward Stats 2011/12</b>')
                                                ]
                                          ),

                                       dict(label='2012/13',
                                           method='update',
                                           args=[{'visible':[False, False, True, True]},
                                                 {'title':'<b>Forward Stats 2012/13</b>'}
                                                ]
                                          ),
                                     ])
                       ),
                  ])

layout = go.Layout(title='<b>Forward Stats</b>',
                   xaxis=dict(title='<b><i>Player Name</b></i>'),
                   yaxis=dict(title='<b><i>Goals/Assists</b></i>'),
                   updatemenus=updatemenus,
                   showlegend=False,
                   barmode='group'
                  )

data = [trace28, trace29, trace30, trace31]
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

I want to display only `trace28` and `trace29` when the plot loads. Right now, all the traces are being shown when the plot loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While making the trace, you can set `visible = "legendonly"`. Then you can toggle the trace by clicking on the line in the legend. Does that do what you want?

So you would change `trace30` and `trace31`

```
trace30 = go.Bar(x=for2.head()['Name'],
                 y=for2.head()['G'],
                 name='Goals',
                 opacity=0.8,
                 visible = "legendonly"
                )

trace31 = go.Bar(x=for2.head()['Name'],
                 y=for2.head()['A'],
                 name='Assists',
                 opacity=0.8,
                 visible = "legendonly"
                )
```

Does that get you your desired functionality?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was able to use this and the other attribute values for **visible** and achieved the desired functionality.